# Extracting one frame per minute with ffmpeg, and skip a few seconds

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I'd like to extract one frame per minute from a video, starting from a specified offset. For example, say the offset is 00:01 (mm:ss), then I'd like to extract 00:01, 01:01, 02:01, and so on.

The problem I've run into is that ffmpeg seems to be rounding my offset down to the nearest minute. If I ask for 00:01, I get 00:00, 01:00, 02:00, and so on. If I give it 01:01, I get 01:00, 02:00, 03:00, and so on.

Additional constraints:

- Subtitles must be rendered. They're in a .ass file in the same directory.
- Each frame should have some text written in the upper-left corner

Here's how I'm invoking ffmpeg for offset `00:01`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "HorribleSubs.mkv" -ss 00:00:01 \
 -vf "ass=HorribleSubs.ass,fps=1/60,drawtext=fontfile=...: fontcolor=white: fontsize=32: x=10: y=10: text=HorribleSubs" \
 "screenshots/%03d-HorribleSubs.png"
```

And here's the output (I ctrl+c'd it when I realized it wasn't working):

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-06-15-8a79a00 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 15 2013 16:36:45 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/sircmpwn/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/sircmpwn/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/sircmpwn/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/sircmpwn/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab --enable-libfreetype
  libavutil      52. 35.101 / 52. 35.101
  libavcodec     55. 16.100 / 55. 16.100
  libavformat    55.  8.102 / 55.  8.102
  libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavfilter     3. 77.101 /  3. 77.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'HorribleSubs.mkv':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2013-05-26 13:34:41
  Duration: 00:23:42.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1900 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30.30 fps, 30.30 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default) (forced)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default) (forced)
    Stream #0:2: Subtitle: ssa (default) (forced)
Codec 0x18000 is not in the full list.
    Stream #0:3: Attachment: unknown_codec
    Metadata:
      filename        : OpenSans-Semibold.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
[Parsed_ass_0 @ 0x19b2100] Added subtitle file: 'HorribleSubs.ass' (9 styles, 374 events)
Output #0, image2, to 'screenshots/%03d-HorribleSubs.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.8.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 0.02 tbc (default) (forced)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> png)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    7 fps=0.5 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:07:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=0    
video:4306kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000499%
Received signal 2: terminating.
```

Comment: I believe this is possible with the [`select`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) filter. I am unable to test at this time to provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg can't really cut everywhere when using h.264 video encoding (which is your case: `Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> png)`).

To make FFmpeg cut everywhere you will need to re-encode the video. try the following:

`ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:01 -i "HorribleSubs.mkv"
 -c:v mpeg2video -g 1
 -vf "ass=HorribleSubs.ass,fps=1/60,drawtext=fontfile=...: fontcolor=white: fontsize=32: x=10: y=10: text=HorribleSubs"
 "screenshots/%03d-HorribleSubs.png"`

Comment: After my own research, I've also found that it'll probably need to be re-encoded. Can you suggest a cheaper encoding than matroska? Re-encoding has added huge amounts of execution time to the script.

Answer (score 0):

This might work: put the -ss in front of the -i so ffmpeg seek to that position before actually doing all the filtering and encoding. Or try LordNeckbeard's solution to use select filter, but I got confused about all those options and variables.

You can go to ffmpeg-users mailing list for some more help.

Comment: This is a very skimpy answer, it should almost be a comment.

Comment: Two problems: one: it doesn't work, and two: it unacceptably reduces seeking accuracy.

Comment: @David Yes, that is what I want to do, but adding a comment to a question requires 50 reputations, but I am a new user to Superuser. :(